# Email Field Validation

Tags: visualforce, email-validation

I have a simple VF form and i would like to validate the email address field when the user click on Submit.

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" showHeader="false" controller="SiteRegisterController" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
    <apex:define name="body">  
      <center>
        <apex:panelGrid bgcolor="white" columns="1"> 
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <apex:panelGrid width="758" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white" columns="1" styleClass="topPanelContainer"> 
            <br/>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="topPanel">
              <apex:panelGrid width="758" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white" columns="2"> 
                <apex:panelGroup >
                  <h1>Don't have an account?</h1>
                  <br/>
                  <h2>Enter your email address to register</h2>
                   <apex:form id="theForm" forceSSL="true">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:1em;">
                      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.site.email}" for="email"/>
                      <apex:inputText required="true" id="email" value="{!email}"/>
                      <apex:outputText value=""/>
                      <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit"/>
                    </apex:panelGrid> 
                    </apex:form>   
                </apex:panelGroup>
              </apex:panelGrid> 
             </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:panelGrid> 
       </apex:panelGrid>
      </center>


      <br/>
    </apex:define> 
</apex:page>
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

BR.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like to do my validation client side, and avoid doing it in Apex server side.  That requires some jQuery knowledge though.  I would use the jQuery Validate plugin.  Very easy to use.  Just need to import the jQuery library and the Validate library.

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#yourFormID").validate({

          rules: {
               name: "required",
               email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
               },
               comment: "required"
          }

     });
});
</script>
```

This ensures that the email is of proper form user@domain.com.  There are lots of other rules and messaging options as well.  Overall, a very easy plugin to use.  Check out the documentation here

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Relying on client-side validation is not a good idea because it can be circumvented. Client-side is good for responsiveness and saving a postback, but user input should not be trusted until validated server-side.

Comment: This is really just a validation of format of the email address, and in no way prevents or restricts you from doing further validation server side.  This is really just a matter of preference and certainly didnt warrant a down vote, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

You can try simple javascript  validation for email listed in W3 school site

```
function validateForm(){

 var x=document.forms["theForm"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
       alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
    }
}

<apex:inputText required="true" id="email" name="email" value="{!email}"/>

 <apex:commandButton action="{!registerUser}" onclick="return validateForm();" value="{!$Label.site.submit}" id="submit"/>
```

Comment: Relying on client-side validation is not a good idea because it can be circumvented. Client-side is good for responsiveness and saving a postback, but user input should not be trusted until validated server-side.